# How to select MySQL rows that have the same content but in different columns?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with three columns, X, Y and Z

```
|    X      |     Y     |      Z    |
-------------------------------------
|   john    |  patrick  |   active  |
|   john    |  miles    | inactive  |
|  patrick  |  john     |   active  |
```

I'd like to select the row data, given 'john' as the input, corresponding to the pair john-patrick - that is, john and patrick are both in either X or Y (like select * rows from TABLE where X = john or Y = john and where ...)

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: See my answer (in response to your request for a good answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the values need to be in X **and** Y
(excluding the tuple ('john', 'miles', 'inactive') in the sample).

Then you will need subquerys for this:

```
select X,Y,Z from TABLE where
  (X = 'john' or Y = 'john') and 
  X in (select Y from TABLE) and
  Y in (select X from TABLE);
```

EDIT: The first query was wrong, thanks to ypercube (see comments).

Corrected version:

```
select X,Y,Z from TABLE where
  (X = 'john' or Y = 'john') and 
  X in (select Y from TABLE as subTable WHERE
         TABLE.X = subTable.Y and TABLE.Y = subTable.X) and
  Y in (select X from TABLE as subTable WHERE
         TABLE.X = subTable.Y and TABLE.Y = subTable.X);
```

Comment: Not a god... this query is very inefficient - it can be done with a simple join to itself (instead of 2 subselects)

Comment: @Rio: Just insert a `(miles,george,active)` record in the table and run it again, to see that it is wrong.

Comment: That's right I'm not a SQL god, but the IN subquery should be as fast as a join when using a state of the art database server. One can have a look at the different query plans.
@ypercube: The new record should not be in the result, because the first condition excludes it.

Comment: @H-Man2: The new record would not be in the result, but the `(john, miles, inactive)` would appear. While there isn't a `(miles,john)` pair.

Comment: It is rather inefficient, it seems. @ypercube/@Bohemian - what would be the better approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a, b, c from test where b  in (select distinct a from test) or a in (select distinct a from test)
john    patrick active
john    miles   inactive
patrick john    active
```

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of ways to solve this problem.  This is just one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE 
    (X = 'john' AND Y = 'patrick')
OR
    (Y = 'john' AND X = 'patrick');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    X, Y, Z 
FROM
    TABLE AS a
  JOIN
    TABLE AS b
      ON  b.X = a.Y
      AND b.Y = a.X
WHERE 
    (a.X = 'john' OR b.X = 'john')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your requirements expressed as SQL:

```
select a.X, a.Y, a.Z
from mytable a
join mytable b on a.X = b.Y and a.Y = b.X
where a.X = 'john';
```

This is very similar to ypercube's answer, but differs in one small but very important way: there is no need for `or b.Y = 'john'` in the where clause, because this is logically covered by the `on` clause of the join (the join says `a.X = b.Y`, so if `a.X = 'john'` we *know already* that `b.Y = 'john'`).

This difference might seem small, but is large in terms of performance: Databases will **not** use indexes when `OR` is used to match indexed columns, ie:

```
where col = 'x' or col = 'y' -- no: will not use index on col

where col = 'x'              -- yes: will use index on col
```

My query will use an index on column X if one exists). If one doesn't exist, create one.

Incidentally, to get the database to use an index in an `OR` on a given column, use `IN` instead. These next two lines are logically identical, but perform very differently

```
where col = 'x' or col = 'y' -- no: will not use index on col

where col in ('x', 'y')      -- yes: will use index on col
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a join for this.

```
select X,Y,Z from users where X like '%john%' or Y like '%john%';
```

Comment: I need the rows that have patrick in them as well wherever there is john.